# как положить не весь обьект в TableView

Tags: java, javafx

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<Area> tableAreas;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Area, String> name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Area, String> width;



   public class Area implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3709082364148217279L;
        private long areaId;
        private String name;
        private String background;
        private int width;
        private int depth;
        private Integer maxCovers;
        private Integer maxReservations;
        private Integer order;
        private boolean active;
}
```

Есть класс Area в котором множество полей, нужно сделать TableView в который нужно положить часть полей из этого класса.
Во всех примерах которые смотрел только целиком объект кладут

Comment: вы же сами определяете колонки (TableColumn) и привязываете их к полям. на выходе будут те колонки, а, соответственно, и поля, которые вы определите. в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @Дмитрий Вопрос в том, как положить объект area в tableView с нужными мне полями

Comment: `tableAreas.getItems().add(new Area(...));` Так же можно добавить сразу список, примерно так: `tableAreas.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(тут List<Area>);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    private StringProperty nameProperty();
    private StringProperty widthProperty();
    // ? private IntegerProperty widthProperty();
}

public class Area implements Serializable, SomeInterface {
   ...
   private StringProperty nameP;

    @Override
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        if ( nameP != null )
            return nameP;
        nameP = new SimpleStringProperty( name );
        return nameP;
    }

    public String getName() {/**/}
    public void setName() {/**/}

    // то же самое с width, только возможно не StringProperty, а IntegerProperty
}

@FXML
private TableView<SomeInterface> tableAreas;
@FXML
private TableColumn<SomeInterface, String> name;
@FXML
private TableColumn<SomeInterface, String> width;
// ? private TableColumn<SomeInterface, Integer> width;
```

Но, как правильно в комментариях заметил @Дмитрий, это не имеет особого смысла, т.к. (цитирую:) *вы же сами определяете колонки (`TableColumn`) и привязываете их к полям*, что-то типа такого будет в вашем коде:

```java
// name column
name.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.nameProperty() );
// width column
width.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.widthProperty() );
```